# android app connects to robot via ip address and port number

Tags: android, wifi

I need to code to connect between my android app and robot via ip address and port number using wifi connection.
I have part of code but I think that it need to commands to create connection.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.10.5", 2525);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
        textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if (socket != null){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null){
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null){
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call flush on your output stream after writing.

Also, close the streams before closing the socket in the finally block.

What is you problem exactly ? 
 Did you look at the logs on the server side to see if connection was established ?
 Do you see that your server accepts the connection ?
 Do you reecive any data on the server side ?

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stéphane.. the problem is when I try running the client app with set ip and port no for robot then the app doesn't work.

Comment: yea, I've tried use previous ways but no results.
my appliction need to pick an access point network to connect to firstly.

Comment: I did not catch your last comment. What do you mean by needs to pick an access point ?

Comment: I mean that the previous code send only commands to server without establish the connect to the server network. so I need to code performs establish this conntion instead I make it manually.